# ST_MakePoint outside PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

To import data into a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database I need this CSV format:

```
"1,nameOfPoint,0101000020E6100000689DA690152F114090338CFF9B0B4A40,2019-07-22 19:56:03.603+00,2019-07-22 19:56:04.243+00"
```

From my understanding the third field is a PostGIS geometry object (created inside PostGIS with `ST_MakePoint`). However I have coordinates. Can I convert coordinates into a PostGIS object outside of the database? Is there a conversion tool for this?

Comment: Postgres will try to cast the input strings using known conversions between `TEXT` and the column type; I can't test right now, but you can try to change the CSV to have a (E)WKT representation of your coordinates. Generally, if this is a recuring task, consider using a trigger.

Comment: @ThingumaBob So when I convert my coordinates using (E)WKT it gives something like `0101000020E6100000689DA690152F114090338CFF9B0B4A40`, right? And what kind of trigger do you mean? Within PostGIS?

Comment: No, I mean to create a EWKT string, e.g  `SRID=<SRID>;POINT(<lon> <lat>)`;  from your coordinates. I think PostGIS should be able to cast that to its geometry type on import (I assume you intend to use `/COPY`?). I would set up an `ON INSERT` trigger in PostgreSQL, though, yes.

Comment: @ThingumaBob Ah... Well, basically I am on Google Cloud SQL (postgres) on which I can export a table and later import it again (no idea whether this uses `/COPY` under the hood...). Now I want to make such an import file myself (instead of from an export) to import it.

Answer (score 1):

The third field should be similar to what you can get with:

```
select encode(ST_AsEWKB(geom),'hex')
```

So it should be ewkb behind, displayed in hexadecimal. I find it not really easy to generate and pass it between computers, and especially to debug.
You can find library to use it in different languages like python with [plpygis](https://pypi.org/project/plpygis/)

Personnally, I prefer to import it in text (ewkt typically) (I'm not sure about the ', maybe you don't need these):

```
"1,nameOfPoint,'POINT(2.3 3.4)',2019-07-22 19:56:03.603+00,2019-07-22 19:56:04.243+00"
```

And add a geometry column afterward with:

```
SELECT AddGeometryColumn ('my_schema','my_spatial_table','geom',4326,'POINT',2);
UPDATE my_spatial_table SET geom = ST_GeomFromEWKT(my_ewkt_field);
```

Note that if you have performance issues while doing so, it's quicker to create a new table instead updating one.

Comment: Cool, so I suppose with javascript this [wkx](https://github.com/cschwarz/wkx) one should work?!

Comment: I didn't test, but it's possible yes, if you write your ewkb in hex

Comment: Will try and get back!